# How to set mydata to axios GET data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, get

I want to send lists(in Content) to mainData
and then in mainData I want to set the lists to respone.data
(so lists(in Content) is set to response.data) HOW CAN I DO IT ?? please help me... :(

// Content. js

```
const Content = (props) => {
    const [lists, setLists] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        mainData(setLists, props.url);
    }, []);
```

// mainData.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const mainData = async({setLists, url}) => {
    try {
        setLists(null);
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        setLists(response.data);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo. `mainData` should accept two arguments, not a single destructured object... `const mainData = async (setLists, url) => { ... }`

Answer (score -1):

A GET request is not designed to upload data. You need to make a POST request, and set the {data: "something"} option in the request config for that to work.

Comment: No, I don't want to upload data. I just want to change my variable to GET request data(=response.data)